# Android - Device movement does not work precisely

Tags: java, android, accelerometer

I have implemented the following code. Basically, I am only looking for the movement of the device not its position. So the impulse. If you suddenly move the device to right, my `onMoveRight()` function will be called. I am using the accelerometer

The **problem** is that when i move to right, it's as if the `onMoveRight()` is called **and** right after it the `onMoveLeft()` is called!!! It isn't precise. It does what I want but then my other functions are called as well!!

my accelerometer period (update) is 100 ms. I tried making it more, but then it doesn't listen to the movement. Or it listens but very late

```java
    if (mLastAcc == null) {
        mLastAcc = acc;
    }

    double xChange = mLastAcc.x - acc.x;
    double yChange = mLastAcc.y - acc.y; 

    if(xChange < -2.0)
    {
        mContext.onMoveRight();
    }
    else if(xChange > 2.0)
    {
        mContext.onMoveLeft();
    }
    else if(yChange > 2.0)
    {
        mContext.onMoveDown();
    }
    else if(yChange < -2.0)
    {
        mContext.onMoveUp();
    }

    mLastAcc = acc;
```

Comment: when you move to the right you start with accellerating to the right but you must also stop. And at that point you decellerate / accellerate to the left. And that is probably what is evaluated as move to the left.

Answer (score 0):

As zapl said you are measuring the acceleration, in that case a negative acceleration doesn't mean that the device is moving left, i would suggest:

```
/* these should not be in the loop
double xCoordinate = 0;
double yCoordinate = 0;
double newXCoordinate, newYCoordinate;
*/
/*these lines won't be needed
if (mLastAcc == null) {
    mLastAcc = acc;
}
*/
newXCoordinate = xCoordinate + 0.5 * acc.x*Math.pow(0.1,2);//0.1 is the period update
newYCoordinate = yCoordinate + 0.5 * acc.y*Math.pow(0.1,2);

double xChange = xCoordinate - newXCoordinate;
double yChange = yCoordinate - newYCoordinate;
xCoordinate = newXCoordinate;
yCoordinate = newYCoordinate;

if(xChange < -2.0)
{
    mContext.onMoveRight();
}
else if(xChange > 2.0)
{
    mContext.onMoveLeft();
}
else if(yChange > 2.0)
{
    mContext.onMoveDown();
}
else if(yChange < -2.0)
{
    mContext.onMoveUp();
}
```

Let me know if it works, I had no time to test it.

Comment: unfortunately it does not work.. it doesn't even change anymore